# Maintaining ESP32-C3 (or other ESP32) timer across deep sleep

Tags: esp32, esp-idf, sleep-mode, real-time-clock

I'm looking for a timer on the ESP32-C3 that persists through sleep phases. The system time does and it is fed by one of two clocks as described here: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32c3/api-reference/system/system_time.html

I set the system time to the 17.5 MHz clock in Menuconfig, and I am aware that there will be some drift that occurs over time. However, in testing I found that there is a randomly variable offset between -10 and 100 microseconds that occurs when transitioning in and out of deep sleep

Does anyone know if it is possible to keep that from happening? Perhaps there's a setting I missed that might allow the system time to continue running during any interrupts or flash access. I also know that other ESP32 variants have more deep sleep functionality. Is it possible to run a separate timer from the ULP that will not be affected by sleep transitions?

Minimum code. PPS is coming from a DS3231:

```
#include "esp_sleep.h"
#include "driver/gpio.h"
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/semphr.h"
#include "rom/ets_sys.h"
#include "soc/periph_defs.h"
#include <sys/time.h>

#define PIN_PPS 5
#define CPU_CORE 1

QueueHandle_t binsem;
gptimer_handle_t gptimer = NULL;
RTC_DATA_ATTR uint64_t time1 = 0ULL;
RTC_DATA_ATTR uint64_t time2 = 0ULL;
RTC_DATA_ATTR uint64_t tally = 0ULL;

uint64_t readTOD() {
    struct timeval now;
    gettimeofday(&now, NULL);
    uint64_t time_us = (uint64_t)now.tv_sec * 1000000ULL + (uint64_t)now.tv_usec;

    return time_us;
}

void IRAM_ATTR ppsInterrupt(void* params) {
    uint64_t now = readTOD();
    time2 = time1;
    time1 = now;

    xSemaphoreGiveFromISR(binsem, pdFALSE);
}

void setupPPSPin(void* params) {
    gpio_config_t io_conf;
    io_conf.intr_type = GPIO_INTR_POSEDGE;
    io_conf.pin_bit_mask = 1 << PIN_PPS;
    io_conf.mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
    io_conf.pull_up_en = 1;
    io_conf.pull_down_en = 0;

    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(gpio_install_isr_service(ESP_INTR_FLAG_IRAM));
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(gpio_config(&io_conf));

    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(gpio_isr_handler_add(PIN_PPS, ppsInterrupt, NULL));
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(gpio_intr_enable(PIN_PPS));

    vTaskDelete(NULL);
}

void app_main() {

    binsem = xSemaphoreCreateBinary();

    xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(
        setupPPSPin,        /* Task function. */
        "Int Task",     /* name of task. */
        10000,           /* Stack size of task */
        NULL,            /* parameter of the task */
        1,               /* priority of the task */
        NULL, /* Task handle to keep track of created task */
        CPU_CORE);              /* pin task to core 1 */
    
    uint64_t ticksPerSecond = time1-time2;
    if(ticksPerSecond != 0 && tally == 0) tally = time2;
    
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<4;i++) {
        xSemaphoreTake(binsem, portMAX_DELAY);
        tally+=ticksPerSecond;
        printf("PPS %i: %llu - %llu \t= %lli\n", i, time1, time2, (int64_t)time1-(int64_t)time2);
        // printf("PPS %i: %llu - %llu \t= %lli\n", i, time1, tally, (int64_t)time1-(int64_t)tally);
    }

    esp_sleep_enable_timer_wakeup(1ULL);
    esp_deep_sleep_start();
}
```

Output shows the first two PPS interrupt triggers after wake up with random variability and any subsequent PPS triggers with a consistent timing. Observation over time does show a small but substantial cumulative drift over the inherent drift of the timer otherwise

```
PPS 0: 16452136656003456033 - 16452136656002456002      = 1000031
PPS 1: 16452136656004455944 - 16452136656003456033      = 999911
PPS 2: 16452136656005455916 - 16452136656004455944      = 999972
PPS 3: 16452136656006455888 - 16452136656005455916      = 999972
Disconnected (read failed: [Errno 6] Device not configured)
Reconnecting to /dev/cu.usbmodem1101     Connected!
PPS 0: 16452136656007455953 - 16452136656006455888      = 1000065
PPS 1: 16452136656008455864 - 16452136656007455953      = 999911
PPS 2: 16452136656009455836 - 16452136656008455864      = 999972
PPS 3: 16452136656010455808 - 16452136656009455836      = 999972
Disconnected (read failed: [Errno 6] Device not configured)
Reconnecting to /dev/cu.usbmodem1101     Connected!
PPS 0: 16452136656011455788 - 16452136656010455808      = 999980
PPS 1: 16452136656012455699 - 16452136656011455788      = 999911
PPS 2: 16452136656013455671 - 16452136656012455699      = 999972
PPS 3: 16452136656014455643 - 16452136656013455671      = 999972
Disconnected (read failed: [Errno 6] Device not configured)
Reconnecting to /dev/cu.usbmodem1101     Connected!
PPS 0: 16452136656015455673 - 16452136656014455643      = 1000030
PPS 1: 16452136656016455584 - 16452136656015455673      = 999911
PPS 2: 16452136656017455556 - 16452136656016455584      = 999972
PPS 3: 16452136656018455528 - 16452136656017455556      = 999972
Disconnected (read failed: [Errno 6] Device not configured)
Reconnecting to /dev/cu.usbmodem1101     Connected!
PPS 0: 16452136656019455553 - 16452136656018455528      = 1000025
PPS 1: 16452136656020455464 - 16452136656019455553      = 999911
PPS 2: 16452136656021455436 - 16452136656020455464      = 999972
PPS 3: 16452136656022455408 - 16452136656021455436      = 999972
Disconnected (read failed: [Errno 6] Device not configured)
Reconnecting to /dev/cu.usbmodem1101     Connected!
PPS 0: 16452136656023455434 - 16452136656022455408      = 1000026
PPS 1: 16452136656024455345 - 16452136656023455434      = 999911
PPS 2: 16452136656025455317 - 16452136656024455345      = 999972
PPS 3: 16452136656026455289 - 16452136656025455317      = 999972
Disconnected (read failed: [Errno 6] Device not configured)
Reconnecting to /dev/cu.usbmodem1101     Connected!
PPS 0: 16452136656027455351 - 16452136656026455289      = 1000062
PPS 1: 16452136656028455262 - 16452136656027455351      = 999911
PPS 2: 16452136656029455234 - 16452136656028455262      = 999972
PPS 3: 16452136656030455206 - 16452136656029455234      = 999972
Disconnected (read failed: [Errno 6] Device not configured)
Reconnecting to /dev/cu.usbmodem1101     Connected!
PPS 0: 16452136656031455278 - 16452136656030455206      = 1000072
PPS 1: 16452136656032455190 - 16452136656031455278      = 999912
PPS 2: 16452136656033455162 - 16452136656032455190      = 999972
PPS 3: 16452136656034455134 - 16452136656033455162      = 999972
Disconnected (read failed: [Errno 6] Device not configured)
Reconnecting to /dev/cu.usbmodem1101     Connected!
PPS 0: 16452136656035455173 - 16452136656034455134      = 1000039
PPS 1: 16452136656036455084 - 16452136656035455173      = 999911
PPS 2: 16452136656037455056 - 16452136656036455084      = 999972
PPS 3: 16452136656038455028 - 16452136656037455056      = 999972
Disconnected (read failed: [Errno 6] Device not configured)
Reconnecting to /dev/cu.usbmodem1101     Connected!
PPS 0: 16452136656039454997 - 16452136656038455028      = 999969
PPS 1: 16452136656040454909 - 16452136656039454997      = 999912
PPS 2: 16452136656041454881 - 16452136656040454909      = 999972
PPS 3: 16452136656042454853 - 16452136656041454881      = 999972
Disconnected (read failed: [Errno 6] Device not configured)
Reconnecting to /dev/cu.usbmodem1101     Connected!
PPS 0: 16452136656043454897 - 16452136656042454853      = 1000044
PPS 1: 16452136656044454809 - 16452136656043454897      = 999912
PPS 2: 16452136656045454781 - 16452136656044454809      = 999972
PPS 3: 16452136656046454752 - 16452136656045454781      = 999971
Disconnected (read failed: [Errno 6] Device not configured)
Reconnecting to /dev/cu.usbmodem1101     Connected!
PPS 0: 16452136656047454776 - 16452136656046454752      = 1000024
PPS 1: 16452136656048454687 - 16452136656047454776      = 999911
PPS 2: 16452136656049454659 - 16452136656048454687      = 999972
PPS 3: 16452136656050454631 - 16452136656049454659      = 999972
Disconnected (read failed: [Errno 6] Device not configured)
Reconnecting to /dev/cu.usbmodem1101     Connected!
PPS 0: 16452136656051454644 - 16452136656050454631      = 1000013
PPS 1: 16452136656052454556 - 16452136656051454644      = 999912
PPS 2: 16452136656053454527 - 16452136656052454556      = 999971
PPS 3: 16452136656054454499 - 16452136656053454527      = 999972
Disconnected (read failed: [Errno 6] Device not configured)
Reconnecting to /dev/cu.usbmodem1101     Connected!
PPS 0: 16452136656055454494 - 16452136656054454499      = 999995
PPS 1: 16452136656056454406 - 16452136656055454494      = 999912
PPS 2: 16452136656057454378 - 16452136656056454406      = 999972
PPS 3: 16452136656058454349 - 16452136656057454378      = 999971
Disconnected (read failed: [Errno 6] Device not configured)
Reconnecting to /dev/cu.usbmodem1101     Connected!
PPS 0: 16452136656059454378 - 16452136656058454349      = 1000029
PPS 1: 16452136656060454289 - 16452136656059454378      = 999911
PPS 2: 16452136656061454261 - 16452136656060454289      = 999972
PPS 3: 16452136656062454233 - 16452136656061454261      = 999972
Disconnected (read failed: [Errno 6] Device not configured)
Reconnecting to /dev/cu.usbmodem1101     Connected!
PPS 0: 16452136656063454225 - 16452136656062454233      = 999992
PPS 1: 16452136656064454136 - 16452136656063454225      = 999911
PPS 2: 16452136656065454108 - 16452136656064454136      = 999972
PPS 3: 16452136656066454080 - 16452136656065454108      = 999972
Disconnected (read failed: [Errno 6] Device not configured)
Reconnecting to /dev/cu.usbmodem1101 .   Connected!
PPS 1: 16452136656068454080 - 16452136656067454168      = 999912
PPS 2: 16452136656069454051 - 16452136656068454080      = 999971
PPS 3: 16452136656070454023 - 16452136656069454051      = 999972
Disconnected (read failed: [Errno 6] Device not configured)
Reconnecting to /dev/cu.usbmodem1101     Connected!
PPS 0: 16452136656071454020 - 16452136656070454023      = 999997
PPS 1: 16452136656072453931 - 16452136656071454020      = 999911
PPS 2: 16452136656073453903 - 16452136656072453931      = 999972
PPS 3: 16452136656074453875 - 16452136656073453903      = 999972
Disconnected (read failed: [Errno 6] Device not configured)
Reconnecting to /dev/cu.usbmodem1101     Connected!
PPS 0: 16452136656075453897 - 16452136656074453875      = 1000022
PPS 1: 16452136656076453809 - 16452136656075453897      = 999912
PPS 2: 16452136656077453781 - 16452136656076453809      = 999972
PPS 3: 16452136656078453752 - 16452136656077453781      = 999971
Disconnected (read failed: [Errno 6] Device not configured)
Reconnecting to /dev/cu.usbmodem1101 .   Connected!
PPS 1: 16452136656080453677 - 16452136656079453766      = 999911
PPS 2: 16452136656081453649 - 16452136656080453677      = 999972
PPS 3: 16452136656082453621 - 16452136656081453649      = 999972
Disconnected (read failed: [Errno 6] Device not configured)
Reconnecting to /dev/cu.usbmodem1101     Connected!
PPS 0: 16452136656083453587 - 16452136656082453621      = 999966
PPS 1: 16452136656084453499 - 16452136656083453587      = 999912
PPS 2: 16452136656085453470 - 16452136656084453499      = 999971
PPS 3: 16452136656086453442 - 16452136656085453470      = 999972
Disconnected (read failed: [Errno 6] Device not configured)
Reconnecting to /dev/cu.usbmodem1101     Connected!
PPS 0: 16452136656087453460 - 16452136656086453442      = 1000018
PPS 1: 16452136656088453372 - 16452136656087453460      = 999912
PPS 2: 16452136656089453343 - 16452136656088453372      = 999971
PPS 3: 16452136656090453315 - 16452136656089453343      = 999972
```